# Transparent Text Background Overlap

Tags: html, css, sass

So I've been using Chris's article https://css-tricks.com/multi-line-padded-text/ to help me get some centred text with a background. The only problem is I want the background to be semi transparent and I can't think of a way of doing it. I've played with line height and padding but can't come up with a solution.

What I want to do is stop the backgrounds of each line overlapping but ensure that the space between each line is the same.

```
  <div class="ui-section__component">
   <div class="comp--hero-text">
    <h2>You're all clear, kid. Let's blow this thing and go home! You're all clear, kid. Let's blow this thing and go home!</h2>
   </div>
  </div>


$white: #fff;
$max-width: 1024px;
$small-spacing: 0.75em;

.ui-section__component{
  background-color: green; 
  display: flex; 
  height: 500px;
  width: 700px;
}

.comp--hero-text {
  align-self: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: $max-width - 200px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 80%;

  h2 {
    background-color: rgba($white, 0.85);
    box-decoration-break: clone;
    box-shadow: $small-spacing / 2 0 0 rgba($white, 0.85), -$small-spacing / 2 0 0 rgba($white, 0.85);
    display: inline;
    line-height: 1.5;
    padding: 0.5em 0;
  }
}
```

My code can be found on Code Pen:  http://codepen.io/rmaspero/pen/VmVwNx

Answer (score 0):

Make the `line-height: 1.2` for `.comp--hero-text h2`, like:

```
.comp--hero-text h2 {
  line-height: 2.2;
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.ui-section__component {
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  height: 500px;
  width: 700px;
}

.comp--hero-text {
  align-self: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 824px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 80%;
}
.comp--hero-text h2 {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  box-shadow: 0.375em 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85), -0.375em 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
  display: inline;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 0.15em 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="ui-section__component">
  <div class="comp--hero-text">
    <h2>You're all clear, kid. Let's blow this thing and go home! You're all clear, kid. Let's blow this thing and go home!</h2>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The problem with this being you now have twice the gap between each line than you do on the top of the first and bottom of the last

Comment: @rmaspero Have a look at my updated answer, I've tweaked the padding and line-height a bit. Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could solve this by just eliminating the alpha channel of the background color and changing it to a rgb similar color. Is the easiest solution I can figure out.

```
    h2 {
        background-color: #f6f9f4;
        box-decoration-break: clone;
        box-shadow: $small-spacing / 2 0 0 rgba($white, 0.85), -$small-spacing / 2 0 0 #f6f9f4;
        display: inline;
        line-height: 1.5;
        padding: 0.5em 0;
      }
```

Comment: The point being I want it to be semitransparent as the background will vary and won't always be a block colour.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the line-height of 'comp--hero-text h2'

```
        .comp--hero-text h2{
          line-height: 2;
        }
```

Or you can adjust the padding

```
        .comp--hero-text h2{
          padding: .2em 0;
        }
```

Comment: The problem with this being you now have twice the gap between each line than you do on the top of the first and bottom of the last.